# Can't get JSON array from URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, rest

I'm working with Resteasy and I have launched a resource in the URL: 'localhost:8080/ressources/agences'

When I test in the browser I get:

```
[{"agence":"Agence Kettani","ville":"Agadir","adresse":"Cartier Hassan II, Agadir","tel":"0528252828","fax":null,"idBanque":1,"id":1},
     {"agence":"Abbatoire","ville":"Agadir","adresse":"Abbatoire, 358 ","tel":"0528283569","fax":null,"idBanque":2,"id":2}]
```

but when I try to get the array with jQuery I get this:

```
readyState
    0

responseText
    ""

status
    0

statusText
    "error"

abort
    function()

always
    function()

complete
    function()

done
    function()

error
    function()

fail
    function()

getAllResponseHeaders
    function()

getResponseHeader
    function()

isRejected
    function()

isResolved
    function()

overrideMimeType
    function()

pipe
    function()

promise
    function()

setRequestHeader
    function()

statusCode
    function()

success
    function()

then
    function()
```

This is what I do in Firebug:

```
$.get('http://localhost:8080/Paie1Web/ressources/agences', function(data) {
  return alert(data);
});
```

I already tested `getJSON` and AJAX. How can I correct this?

Comment: Try using [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson) instead of `$.get`. That should set `data` equal to the JSON array.

Comment: I think the console is showing the return of $.get, not the return of the actual http request.

Comment: try `$.get('http://localhost:8080/Paie1Web/ressources/agences', console.log);` and see if it gets logged.

Comment: What domain is your web *page* loading from? Not the JSON data, but the web page that's requesting it. If it's not `localhost:8080` - the same as the JSON data - then you have a cross-site problem.

Comment: This isn't the return data. It seems to be a "Promise Object" you are printing out. Seems like there's missing code you are not telling us here.

Comment: It may just be a typo in your question, but the URLs you've listed are different. You say you test this in the address bar: `localhost:8080/ressources/agences` But use this in jQuery: `http://localhost:8080/Paie1Web/ressources/agences`

Comment: well I tried all the thing you told me: $.getJSON and it's the same result

Comment: I'mworking localy so it's localhost 127.0.0.1 and my JBOSS run's on 8080

Comment: I test this in the browser(localhost:8080/ressources/agences) it gives me the json array and it's the same with http://localhost:8080/Paie1Web/ressources/agences

Comment: That's not what responded from server, It's AJAX instances it's self. try this to see your data:

$.get('http://localhost:8080/Paie1Web/ressources/agences',function(data) {console.log($.parseJSON(data));});

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes on success, the ajax payload is not loaded yet due to latency, server slowdown, whatever, so you need to handle that you could use complete or done (depending on the version you are using), maybe like this:

```
var payload = {};
$.get('http://localhost:8080/Paie1Web/ressources/agences', function(data) {
   $.extend(
      true,      //this forces the object to be deep copied
      payload,   //the target object to extend
      data       //Extend to this object
   );
}, 'json').complete(function(){
   //do what ever you want here with the extended payload
});
```

I think that would work

Comment: I've never seen this happen before.